# Create future dataframe with neuralprophet when using autoregression

Tags: python, forecasting, facebook-prophet, prophet

I tried adding future datafame using

```
future = m.make_future_dataframe(df, periods= 720, n_historic_predictions=True)
```

However, only 1 row is added to the dataframe, instead of 720 rows.

Model code :

```
m = NeuralProphet(
    changepoints_range=0.95,
    normalize='soft', 
    n_changepoints=50,
    trend_reg=1,
    yearly_seasonality=False,
    weekly_seasonality=True,
    daily_seasonality=10,
    n_lags = 7 # If i remove this line the future dataframe works just fine
)
m.add_seasonality(name="monthly", period=30.5, fourier_order=5)
m.set_plotting_backend("plotly")
metrics = m.fit(df, freq="H")
```

The documentation didnt mention anything that AR would affect make_future_dataframe feature
https://neuralprophet.com/code/forecaster.html

> Extends dataframe a number of periods (time steps) into the future.Only use if you predict into the unknown future. New timestamps are added to the historic dataframe, with the ‘y’ column being NaN, as it remains to be predicted. Further, the given future events and regressors are added to the periods new timestamps. The returned dataframe will include historic data needed to additionally produce n_historic_predictions, for which there are historic observances of the series ‘y’.